# How to fix error object has no attribute '_build_add_commands' when creating def __init__ function with flet library

Tags: python, flutter, flet

This is my first time using the flet library and trying to create a def **init** function. However, when I run the error object has no attribute '_build_add_commands' appears and I don't understand it

```
import flet 
from flet import *



class Try():
    def __init__(self, page:Page):
        self.page = page
        self.text=flet.Text("Hello")
        


def main(page:flet.Page):
    page.add(Try(page))
flet.app(target=main)
```

How do I get the hello text to appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [User Controls](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/user-controls) like this:

```
import flet


class Try(flet.UserControl):
    def build(self):
        return flet.Text("Hello")


def main(page: flet.Page):
    page.add(Try())


flet.app(target=main)
```

It is not necessary to parse the page reference to Try().